# Configure Matomo to send emails using AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: matomo, amazon-simple-email-service

My Matomo instances have been logging messages like this for a while:

```
2022-08-31 06:57:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Signature Version 2 is deprecated for use with SES from March 26, 2021. From that date on, we are progressively rejecting such requests. To resolve the issue, you must migrate to Signature Version 4. If you created your SMTP credentials in the SES Console, please create new credentials and replace the former ones. If you are deriving Signature Version 2 credentials from a IAM user, please start using the Signature Version 4 algorithm: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentia
2022-08-31 06:57:46 SMTP ERROR: User & Password command failed: 535 Signature Version 2 is deprecated for use with SES from March 26, 2021. From that date on, we are progressively rejecting such requests. To resolve the issue, you must migrate to Signature Version 4. If you created your SMTP credentials in the SES Console, please create new credentials and replace the former ones. If you are deriving Signature Version 2 credentials from a IAM user, please start using the Signature Version 4 algorithm: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentia
2022-08-31 06:57:46 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

So I created a new SMTP user that should have the new signature automatically (At least I hope so). Then I got 3 values from AWS:

- IAM User Name
- Smtp Username
- Smtp Password

Now I am wondering, why the connection does not work at all anymore. My `config.ini.php` now looks like this:

```
[mail]
transport = "smtp"
port = 25
host = "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
type = "Login"
encryption = "tls"
username = "[[Smtp Username]]"
password = "[[Smtp Password]]"
```

Do I need to use a different `type` or `encryption`, so the mails are sent again?

Currently the error message says:

```
Uncaught exception: /var/www/html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(2178): SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. [Query: , CLI mode: 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different ports?
Check this part of Amazon documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-smtp-software-package.html

I had a problem with setting up a connection with different tools (Grafana and Sendgrid) and I had to skip the certificate verification process (ref. https://piotr.gg/dev-ops/setup-grafana-email-notification-via-sendgrid-smtp-also-for-bitnami-grafana.html)